# 2-litre pack of duty-free spirits, but the limit is 1 litre

Tags: duty-free

The World Duty Free shop in Heathrow sells boxes containing 2x1-litre bottles of spirits (~40% alcohol), advertising them as "Duty Free", and "For all passengers travelling OUTSIDE the UK". Staff confirmed that the duty-free limit for travelling outside of the UK is 1 litre. But these offers clearly contain 2L in an unopened box intended for a single purchase on a single boarding pass.

As someone travelling from London Heathrow to an EU country (Republic of Ireland), how is it possible to buy and transport double the duty-free limit in this form? What is the intended use of these products?

Comment: *the duty-free limit for travelling outside of the UK is 1 litre.* There's not usually a limit on how much alcohol you can take *out* of a country. The limit is usually on what you take *into* a country.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/bringing-goods-into-uk-personal-use/arriving-in-Great-Britain  says 4l here.

Comment: Think outside the box: simply consume one of the two bottles before hitting Irish customs. Your neighbors on the plane might offer to help.

Comment: "What is the intended use of these products?": It is to bring into countries that allow free import of that amount. For example Dubai allows 4 liters. There is no "export limit" only "import limits" what vary from country to country.

Comment: @StephanKolassa if you try to do that on the actual plane you are probably violating the terms of carriage or other regulations.

Answer (score 67):

That's my job right there (I sell alcohol to duty-free operators), so I have a little insight.

Let's work first on the Duty-Free concept. What makes the products duty-free is not that you can buy 1 litre, 2, 6. It's that they were never taxed by the government. In the case of locally-made whisky for instance, no excise, not VAT, nothing. Straight from the distillers to a bonded warehouse, and onwards to the DF shops. And for imported products, say a French Cognac, or a US bourbon, no import tax, excise, VAT. Straight from the ship to the same bonded warehouse. In either case, the products never hit the domestic market, and are not fit to be sold locally. Which is why they mention *For all passengers travelling OUTSIDE the UK.*

The mention

> Staff confirmed that the duty-free limit for travelling outside of the UK is 1 litre.

is incorrect. You can take as many litres as you want. The one-litre duty-free limit is for import into Ireland (if you're flying to another country, the limit could be different).

So indeed, you could buy a full suitcase worth of booze, as I've seen people do (why do you think in many airports liquor DF stores give away suitcases?), and they're all duty-free. At the point of purchase. It's duty-free for export.

Now, when you land somewhere else, a new set of problems crop up. The duty-free allowance for import. Different floor, arrivals vs departures, different rules. That country's Customs service allows incoming passengers to bring in a certain amount of alcohol, tobacco, perfume, etc, without having to pay tax on them, and if they exceed that amount they will have to pay tax on the remainder. Fair enough.

Some people may gamble, and hope they won't get caught at their destination. In which case good deal, they got booze at a cheaper cost. That two-bottle deal worked for them. In other cases, they could be travelling with Da Missus, who's buying perfume next door. John buys a two-litre pack, and if stopped by Customs on arrival, points at Jane. *Two of us, Guv, two bottles.*

And finally, there's the case where John fully knows he bought 1 bottle over the limit, and intends to abide by the law. He goes to the "Goods to declare" lane, to pay the tax on the 2nd bottle, of his own volition. He might still get a good deal, in the sense that the cost of the 2 bottles, one untaxed, one taxed, is lower than buying 2 bottles at destination (especially in countries with heavy taxes on booze). This works in countries that don't tax everything if you exceed the DF allowance, as mentioned by @Jack below in the comments.

The fact is, "duty-free" means that no government **levied** taxes on the products in the country of purchase. Past tense. It's not a promise another government (or the same government if you bring the alcohol back) won't tax you when crossing a border.

Comment: A least in Australia, if you are over the limit, you pay tax on *all* items in that category, not just the items over the limit https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/duty-free

Comment: @Jack Interesting, thanks. Never seen that done before (and I don't sell there, yet anyway).

Comment: Note that in some countries the limit is strictly by passenger and cannot be pooled.

Comment: @jcaron Easily circumvented if you unpack and distribute. The duty-allowance does not apply solely to products bought in DF stores, but to everything one has. I see this done all the time. Chinese shoppers – possibly the largest group of clients – do this all the time.

Comment: @dda certainly works for a pack of 2 x 1 l bottles as in OP's case, but won't work for a single 2 l bottle of course

Comment: Note that splitting it among travellers doesn't work with children. And may not work with adults if they suspect you're trying it on (although in most cases you'll be OK).

Comment: Indeed (to last 2 comments). Also, if you're local to the destination, there's often a minimum overseas stay period. 24 or 48 hours. Varies by country/region.

Comment: @jcaron "Wanna help me get rid of this little problem, officer?" (Uncorks the 20 year Cognac bottle.)

Comment: @jcaron And actually -- it has a certain aesthetic dissonance, but the booze probably doesn't suffer too much from temporarily being in a Columbia water bottle...

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica And of course since customs officials have **no experince** with smugglers at all, they won't wonder why you have a fluid container larger than the allowed 100ml that you may take with you in a airplane.

Comment: @StuartF: "And may not work with adults if they suspect you're trying it on" In what way would someone be "trying it on"? e.g. Here are 5 bottles. Here are 5 travellers. They are each entitled to bring in a bottle. That seems to follow the letter AND the spirit (no pun intended) of the law.

Comment: @markjohnson you realize that there are shops selling soft drinks bottles, and even empty bottles, airside, in many airports, right?

Comment: @dda Yes, but you (and others) realise that customs officials are trained in catching smugglers? They learn all the tricks of the day gathered in the last centuries of their profession.

Comment: @Oddthinking: In Thailand, if customs finds 5 liters of alcohol in your bag (which they will if they make you put your bag through their x-ray machine) then you'll be threatened with all sorts of unpleasantness (jail--you don't have an import license for alcohol) unless you surrender 4 liters to be "destroyed" for you by customs.  It doesn't matter if there are 4 other adults traveling on the same ticket with you that have nothing in their bags.  The limit is 1 liter per person.  No sharing.

Comment: @MarkJohnson - You're allowed more than 100ml of liquid on a plane though. You're not allowed is to take more than 100ml of liquid through security.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You can carry *empty* fluid containers of any size through security and later fill them. Also, customs inspection is *after* picking up checked bags, so at that point there is no reason you cannot have liquids of any size, whether purchased airside or not. There may indeed be patterns that officials are suspicious of, but your description of "a fluid container larger than the allowed 100ml that you may take with you in a airplane" doesn't seem pertinent.